# Hello! I need some help in updating LIstView in Fragments

Tags: android

How can I update ListView in the other Fragment?

```
public class ChooseCS extends FragmentActivity {

final private Context context = this;

private HashMap<String, List<String>> mCitiesStreets = null;

private View rootViewStreetChangeFragment = null;
private SimpleAdapter adapter;
```

...

```
private static final int NUM_PAGES = 3;

private ViewPager mPager;

private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
```

...

and two Fragments

```
public class CityChangeFragment extends Fragment {
```

and

```
public class StreetChangeFragment extends Fragment {
```

...

```
    mMapDataAdapter.put("streets", fillcities);
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                rootViewStreetChangeFragment.getContext(),
                mMapDataAdapter.get("streets"), R.layout.grid_streets_4_7,
                from, to);
        mDataListViewStreets.setAdapter(adapter);
```

...

I need make update ListView in StreetChangeFragment from CityChangeFragment where I doing changing data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LocalBroadcastManager to achieve this.

In your StreetChangeFragment write below code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...

// Register to receive messages.
// We are registering an observer (mMessageReceiver) to receive Intents
// with actions named "custom-event-name".
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
  new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));
}

// Our handler for received Intents. This will be called whenever an Intent
// with an action named "custom-event-name" is broadcasted.
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
// Get extra data included in the Intent
String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
}
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
// Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
super.onDestroy();
}
```

And use below method to send broadcast message from CityChangeFragment  to StreetChangeFragment

```
private void sendMessage() {
  Log.d("sender", "Broadcasting message");
  Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
  // You can also include some extra data.
  intent.putExtra("message", "This is my message!");
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Note: You can pass data using intent (here you can position also on which you want to update data in listview)

You can check below link to learn more about LocalBroadcastManager

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html

Comment: I found this way
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
     Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
    }
   };
   // Register to receive messages.
   // We are registering an observer (mMessageReceiver) to receive
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(
     mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));

Answer (score 0):

Interface is good idea,The idea is basically to define an interface  and let the activity implement that interface.

Once it has implemented that interface, you could do anything you want in the method it overrides.
There is a good tutorial on  [Simple Developer Blog](http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/) how to do exactly this kind of thing.

And you need t declare a method in fragment and it can be executed from the activity by getting the fragment instance from adapter like

```
   Fragment fragment= mPagerAdapter.getItem(int positon);
   ((StreetChangeFragment )).updateList();
```

in StreetChangeFragment declare method and do what else you want, Thank you